# Stop SQL Reporting Server Hijacking /Reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

How do you stop SQL server reporting services from hijacking the /reports virtual folder on ALL websites on the server it's installed on. Have just discovered that all the websites on the box with the reporting server on (its a dev box), have /Reports overridden by the reporting services manager. How do I turn this off?

Have tried stopping the service, disabling it in the config file, all to no avail (the service is still hijacking the url, you just get a "service unavailable" error instead of the report manager). Short of uninstalling reporting services, is there a way to switch this off?

Comment: Could you give us an example of the URLs you're using, for (1) the case where you're going to the Report Server reports folder as expected, and (2) the case when you're seeing the "hijacking"?

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe and that there is an answer for this already on SO somewhere...

Answer (score 9):

I had the exact same problem - very annoying when your own web application uses a /Reports folder, couldn't understand why I was getting "File or Directory Not Found" errors on IIS when navigating to my reports page.

Phil is correct the easiest solution (using SQL Server 2008 R2) is to run Reporting Services Configuration Manager, connect to your local instance and change the Virtual Directory under "Report Manager URL" to something more unique (I used "/ReportingServices").

This fixed the problem and my /Reports folder was restored to my own web app!

Comment: This was the solution for me.

Comment: Fought with this for most of the day yesterday until stumbling upon the fact it was the reporting server. Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server 2008 R2 reporting services you can do this via the Reporting Services Configuration Manager.

But consider telling us the version of reporting services.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the port it listens to via the Reporting Services Configuration Manager.
I have set mine to `8080` instead of `80`, and it has solved the problem for me.